# Connection between magento with RabbitMQ

Tags: magento2.4, rabbit-mq

How to ensure the connection between RabbitMQ and Magento 2.

Please help me to sort out this.

I have successfully configured the RabbitMQ with Magento 2, And I have configured the same in my AWS server.

But the bulk product import response throws the 500 internal server error.

Please help

[image]

"Invalid frame type 72"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if there are queues created, if not, run the setup upgrade. This command below shows the RabbitMQ list if your Magento is connected.

```
python3 /usr/bin/rabbitmqadmin --host rabbitmq -u username -p 8b2sovjbgg4atsbpn0s0oam9y6vekh6i list queues
```

Don't forget to check the connection in your `app/etc/env.php`

[image: Magento 2 RabbitMQ]